# Spring.Net throwing "Cannot activate transaction synchronization - already active" for nested transations in a multithreaded application

Tags: c#-4.0, rabbitmq, spring.net

### Background:

We are using Spring.Net 2.0 to manage our transactions with nHibernate 3.3.1. The application follows the the publisher-subscriber pattern. Each subscriber runs in a separate thread and is invoked by RabbitMQ message broker system once the queue, it is bound to, got a message published from some other thread.

Each time the subscriber begins processing it starts a new transaction (using Spring.Net declarative transactions support) in a separate thread. All the subsequent operations invoked by subscriber usually use the same transaction. But there are cases where we need a new transaction e.g. when we need to update the shared data, like oracle sequence. The methods doing such operations are decorated with Transaction aspect and with TransactionPropagation value set as RequiresNew.

Based on spring.Net documentation and source code we assume that for such special scenarios where a method is invoked with TransactionPropagation value as RequiresNew, the outer transaction is suspended until the method is completed. The outer transaction resumes after the completion of the method and follows the execution path of the thread.

### Problem:

We are encountering a random scenario where once a subscriber is handed over the message for processing, some times it completes the task with out any problem but some times it throws following exception:

Exception message:

> Cannot activate transaction synchronization - already active
>
> Stacktrace:    at
> Spring.Transaction.Support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.InitSynchronization()
> at
> Spring.Transaction.Support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.DoResumeSynchronization(IList
> suspendedSynchronizations)    at
> Spring.Transaction.Support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.Resume(Object
> transaction, Object suspendedResources)    at
> Spring.Transaction.Support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.HandleExistingTransaction(ITransactionDefinition
> definition, Object transaction, Boolean debugEnabled)    at
> Spring.Transaction.Support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.GetTransaction(ITransactionDefinition
> definition)    at
> Spring.Transaction.Interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.CreateTransactionIfNecessary(ITransactionAttribute
> sourceAttr, String joinpointIdentification)    at
> Spring.Transaction.Interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.CreateTransactionIfNecessary(MethodInfo
> method, Type targetType)    at
> Spring.Transaction.Interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.Invoke(IMethodInvocation
> invocation)    at
> Spring.Aop.Framework.AbstractMethodInvocation.Proceed() in
> e:\spring.net\spring-net-master\src\Spring\Spring.Aop\Aop\Framework\AbstractMethodInvocation.cs:line
> 291    at Spring.Aop.Framework.DynamicProxy.AdvisedProxy.Invoke(Object
> proxy, Object target, Type targetType, MethodInfo targetMethod,
> MethodInfo proxyMethod, Object[] args, IList interceptors) in
> e:\spring.net\spring-net-master\src\Spring\Spring.Aop\Aop\Framework\DynamicProxy\AdvisedProxy.cs:line
> 210

**The frequency of this issue increases with number of messages in the message broker queues**.

### Sample Code/Configuration:

The spring transaction is configured in our spring context file as:

```
<object id="transactionManager" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager, Spring.Data.NHibernate3">
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider" />
  <property name="SessionFactory" ref="NHibernateSessionFactory" />
  <property name="TransactionSynchronization" value="Always" />
</object>
```

The code is written like:

```
public class MyMessageHandler   
{
    ServiceOne MyServiceOne { get; set;}
    ServiceTwo MyServiceTwo { get; set;}

    [Transaction]
    public void Execute()
    {
        var unprocessedObjects = MyServiceOne.FindUnprocessedObjects();
        
        foreach (var unprocessedObject in unprocessedObjects)
        {
            MyServiceTwo.UpdateObject(unprocessedObject); //----> This is where exception is being thrown
        }
    }
}
public class ServiceOne 
{
    [Transaction]
    public List<MyType> FindUnprocessedObjects()
    {
        return TestRepository.FindUnprocessedObjects();
    }
}
public class ServiceTwo 
{
    [Transaction(TransactionPropagation.RequiresNew)]
    public List<MyType> UpdateObject(MyType obj)
    {
        var myObj = this.GetCurrentSession().Merge(obj);
        myObj.Processed = true; 
    }
}
```

We are stuck as we could not see a real reason whey above code is running some times without problem but throwing exception randomly. Please help.

Regards